# activate a profile which is in a different pom when building from the project parent pom

Tags: java, maven, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I am having a challenge where by i want to activate a profile which is in a different pom file and it is not added as a module on the project, but in this instance i want to activate it along with my parent pom which will build the entire project

Comment: Can you give a directory layout example and what is the purpose of that profile?

Comment: have you tried putitng the profile in the parent? Worst case you can always place profiles in the maven settings.

Comment: I managed to do it, i added the project as a profile to my super pom and only activate it when i run the super pom with -P